# Updating ESTA details for second visit to USA

Tags: usa, esta, australian-citizens

My ESTA is valid until Jan 2016. I am holding an Australian passport valid until 2017. I already made one trip to USA in May 2014. I will travel from Australia to USA in Sep 2015.

I have updated the new address where I will stay during the second visit on the web site of US Custom Border Protection. However I am still concerned about the flight details (airlines, flight number etc...) which I could not update.

Why not, or how do I, or need I not?

Comment: You do not need to update all the flight details in ESTA. And, since you have visited the US before, you can use the automated passport kiosks on your next visit, to speed things up. Follow the signs for Automated Passport Control.

Answer (score 3):

For **What information can I update?**
[U.S. Customs and Border Protection](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#uta1) has:

> Prior to submitting an electronic travel authorization application with the required payment information, you can update all application data fields except the passport number and passport issuing country. Once an application is complete and submitted with all the required payment information, you can still update any one of the following fields:

```
E-mail address
Address in the U.S.
```

It is a guess, but I suspect you can't update your travel details because these will be provided automatically through the APIS system.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this a couple of times within the last years (visiting to the US with an existing ESTA) and there were never any problems. Simply update the information you *can* update and simply leave the flight number as it is.

I don't think it makes a big difference as there is always the scenario where you're rebooked by the airline to another flight on short notice and wouldn't have a change to update the ESTA information.