# To obtain WB status, should I renew my ESTA (it was used for a tourist travel before)?

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program, business-travel, visa-renewals

Note: As kindly mentioned by Jan Doggen, this question is new, because I specifically talk about diffrence between business vs. tourist ESTA and how to obtain WB status.

I (german) applied for ESTA Dec 2015, it is valid until Dec 2017. I used it for a tourist trip in Dec 2015, and all information are according to that. I can only update the adress of my residence in the US.

I will go to the US again in May 2017 as visiting researcher for less than 90 days and hope to obtain Waiver Buisiness (WB) status uppon arrival.

Should I renew my ESTA to update all information (contact person, residence, travel reason, and so on) or should it also work with the current ESTA?

Comment: A difference with that other question may be that here the OP specifically talks about different reasons to visit (business vs. tourist) *and* wants to apply for WB status

Comment: Are you a time traveller? ;)

Comment: Thank you Jan. I editet the question. How can I 'unduplicate' it?

Comment: "Once approved, an ESTA is valid for two years, and can be used multiple times, provided the reason for the multiple visits to the US remains within the scope of the VWP: business or tourism." -- this is already said in the canonical so I do not see a reason for a reopen.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "business ESTA" or a "tourist ESTA."  There's just ESTA.  Follow the advice in [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/53634/19400): update whatever information you can and leave the rest.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. I will not renew the ESTA then. I also saw that there is no Information asked in the ESTA concerning reason of trevel. So the only information I can not update that would be relevant is contact person.